# I deleted /dev/stdout on Cygwin. How can I restore it? How can I prevent it from happening again?

Tags: cygwin, stdout, symlink

Basically I ran the following as a test:

```
$ gcc -c -xc - -o /dev/stdout <<<'int main(){return 0;}'
```

I got an error (`Fatal error: can't write /dev/stdout: Illegal seek`), and I then found that (presumably as a clean-up step) `gcc` deleted `/dev/stdout`. Now when I run for example `echo foo > /dev/stdout`, it just creates an ordinary text file at that location.

Can I just create it again as a symlink?:

```
$ ln -s /proc/self/fd/1 /dev/stdout
```

Or is there more to it than that?

How can I prevent this from happening again? I realize that `/dev/stdout` needs to have write permissions for everyone for it to work properly.